# Java Как разделить число на цифры?

Tags: java

Здравствуйте, я новичек в джаве, может кто-нибудь помочь с заданием?
Нужно: 
1. Ввести трехзначное число
2. Ввести количество  чисел справа.

**Вообщем сам вопрос:** как разделить это трехзначное число на цифры? Если например вести число 657 и количество чисел справа 2, чтоб получить 57. Что нужно использовать?

Comment: Деление нужно использовать и остаток от деления.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов зачем? если есть substring и parseInt?

Comment: @pwnsauce берем число конвертируем в строку. Дальше используем метод `substring`, чтоб взять последние символы, далее через `Integer.parseInt(ВАША_СТРОКА_С_ЧИСЛОМ)` конвертируется в целое число

Comment: Вы же только что в ответе на мой вопрос написали что лучше наоборот )

Answer (score 3):

Ищем остаток от деления на 10^а.

```
import java.util.*;
class Program
{ 
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int n,a;
    try (Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in))
    {
        n = in.nextInt();
        a = in.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println(n%(int)Math.pow(10,a));
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Program
{ 
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Введите число");
    int num = s.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Введите количество цифр");
    int numcount = s.nextInt();
    if(numcount.length > count) System.out.println("Не могу не умею");
    else {
         //способ 1
         String s = Integer.toString(num);
         System.out.println(s.substring(s.length() - numcount));

         //способ 2
         int j = (int) Math.pow(10, numcount);
         int result = numcount % j;
    }
}
}
```