# In (число) t в массив по цифрам

Tags: java

У меня есть число int, условно "123". Нужно перенести его в массив int[] по цифрам, то бишь [1, 2, 3]. Как это можно сделать? Я искал в инете и тут, но решений рабочих и простых не нашел. Если не сложно, опишите также работу своего варианта.

Comment: C помощью остатка от деления %

Comment: Ни одного рабочего решения? [Разбиение числа на цифры независимо от длины - 2011 год, 10 ответов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/896257/), [Как разделить число в цифры в java - 2018 год, 5 ответов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/896257/), [Java Как разделить число на цифры? -2016 год, 2 ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/584305/); [Запись цифр числа в массив - 2019, 3 ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1058001/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы это осуществить нужно выполнить этот код:

```
int nums = 12345; 
String text = nums + ""; 
int[] arr = new int[text.length()];

for(int i = 0; i<text.length(); i++){
  arr[i] = nums%10;
  nums /= 10;
```

Как работает этот код:

1. Мы создаём массив с длиной, равной количеству символов числа
2. Мы берём последний символ числа
3. Мы обрезаем последний символ(nums/10) возвращаемся к пункту 3 и снова берём последний символ числа
4. И так до тех пор, пока массив не заполнится

Comment: Все работает, но есть 2 вопроса еще) 
arr[i] = nums%10; и nums /= 10; Что происходит в эти моменты?

Оно же делит число на 10 и берет число после запятой себе в массив, а после удаляет это число после запятой округляя его. Но как это происходит?

Comment: `с длиной, равной количеству символов числа` -  получается двойная работа. Раз уж перевели число в строку, ну и используйте готовое разложение

Comment: в "arr[i] = nums % 10" мы берём из nums последний символ(или остаток от деления)(Пример: 123%10 = 3), а "в nums =/ 10" мы удаляем из nums одну цифру(Пример: 123/10 = 12), чтобы снова взять последнюю цифру из нового числа(Пример: 12%10 = 2), и получается, что мы берём каждую цифру числа и кладём её в массив. Вот так и работает.

Answer (score 0):

Это можно сделать таким образом:

```
int number = 123;
int digitsTotal = (int)(Math.log10(number)+1);
int[] digitsArray = new int[digitsTotal];
for (int i = digitsTotal - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    digitsArray[i] = number % 10;
    number /= 10;
}
```

Ваше число - **number**.
Массив цифр - **digitsArray**.

Цикл сделал наоборот потому, что при остатке от деления на 10 мы получаем последнюю цифру числа.

Comment: А что делает строка int digitsTotal = (int)(Math.log10(number)+1); ?

Comment: @Surion помогает понять, массив какого размера нужно создать (cчитает кол-во цифр в числе).
Можно сделать с ArrayList и тогда это будет не нужно. Цикл тогда завершится тогда, когда number < 1

Comment: У меня ввод идет int n, по условиям в нем только двоичный код. Твой вариант работает, но я заменил все number на свой n и результат такой.
n = 00000000000000000000000010000000
Output = 
8
2
1

Answer (score 0):

Пусть есть число:

```java
int integer = 123;
```

Чтобы получить массив цифр, сначала преобразуем это число в строку, а затем из каждого символа строки вычтем символ `'0'`:

```java
int[] integers = String.valueOf(integer).chars().map(ch -> ch - '0').toArray();
```

То же самое можно сделать без использования стримов:

```java
char[] chars = String.valueOf(integer).toCharArray();
int[] integers = new int[chars.length];
for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
    integers[i] = chars[i] - '0';
}
```

Результат:

```java
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(integers)); // => [1, 2, 3]
```